# Sending a local stream to multiple remote peers

Tags: webrtc

How do I send my local video stream to multiple remote peers? Do I need to instantiate one `PeerConnection` per remote peer? Or can the same `PeerConnection` be used for all remote peers at the same time?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to user `dom` on [#webrtc on irc.w3.org](http://irc.w3.org/), each PeerConnection is associated with a single remote peer. The developer is responsible for sharing the same stream instance with multiple `PeerConnections`:

```
<Cow_woC> Can a single PeerConnection connect to multiple remote peers, or only a single one at a time? If I want to stream the same video to multiple remote peers, what am I supposed to do?
<dom> Cow_woC, you need to manage several PeerConnection objects
<dom> and plug your video stream to each of them
<Cow_woC> dom: How do I share the camera feed with multiple PeerConnections? Is getUserMedia() allowed to return the same resource (and share it) multiple times?
<Cow_woC> dom: Or am I responsible for keeping the reference around and passing it to multiple PeerConnections?
<dom> the latter
```

Comment: Great Help! Thank you