# How to do a group video call and group audio call using PubNub

Tags: android, video, chat, pubnub

I went through Android Example of PubNub of video calling and chatting. Here is a link I followed. https://github.com/pubnub/android-webrtc-api

But I did not find a way to do a video and audio group call.

Comment: PubNub does not provide WebRTC services, rather PubNub is used to implement the signal protocol part of a complete WebRTC solution. So it's a matter of just taking the example and and extending it to more than one user. For a more complete understand of WebRTC and PubNub's role (what it does what it does not do), see the KB article [Does PubNub Provide WebRTC and Video Chat?](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/252/does-pubnub-provide-webrtc-and-video-chat#latest). There are some solutions/pointers that might get you going in the right direction (hint, look at http://sinch.com).

Answer (score 0):

WebRtc might not be what you want. Try Androidrtc if you haven't already. This example has helped me tremendously.

https://github.com/GleasonK/AndroidRTC

Comment: Yes I have tried it, but troubling to extend for multiple users. Any help or sample code will be appreciated.

Comment: By multiple users are you meaning video users? There is a post on here somewhere that shows how a user modified this code to allow it. I don't have time to search for it, but I'll post link when I find it.

Comment: @Kaustubh - I found the article and was mistaken, it is with WebRTC. But here is the link if you are interested. Good luck!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32928874/how-to-implement-3-way-conference-call-video-chat-with-webrtc-native-code-for-an/33049607#33049607