# Multiparty audio in WebRTC on iOS/Android is garbled

Tags: android, ios, webrtc, video-conferencing

I'm trying to figure out what's the best way of doing the following: having a peer connection between parties A and B, I want to add a third party C, but the difficulty is that I don't want a full mesh configuration, B should communicate with C only through A (an MCU setup, where A is the MCU).

```
B <-> A <-> C
```

What I tried so far is the following: when the peerConnectionAC is created and the didAddStream callback is called, I add the peerConnectionAB.remoteStream as a local stream to peerConnectionAC, like so:

```
peerConnectionAC.addStream(remoteStreamAB)
```

Then, I do it the other way around:

```
peerConnectionAB.addStream(remoteStreamAC)
```

At this point WebRTC triggers the renegotiation callback so a new offer is generated and sent to the respective parties.

Audio is now flowing between B and C through A, but it's terribly garbled, almost unintelligible. Audio flowing from A's microphone to B and C is still clear.

Both peer connections are using the same codec (OPUS, but also tried with iLBC) and the same sample rate.

The only reference I found for this is [a question from over half a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39579653/android-webrtc-mix-audiotracks-for-conference), but without a clear answer.

This appears to be [easily done in a browser setup](https://webrtchacks.com/web-audio-conference/), but I need it to work on iOS/Android as a standalone app.

Can anyone give me an idea or a pointer on how to fix the garbled audio?

Comment: You need to provide more info, for instance: Are you communicating over WIFI or 3G/4G? Are you using STUN or TURN servers? Could you post WebRTC stats between A - C, A - B and C - B (through A)?

Comment: For simplicity's sake, assume all three devices are on the same wifi with excellent connectivity.